# Restrict Google Forms Responses in QuestionGrid

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am rather new to Google Scripting, but I am currently working on a project which utilizes it for creating a Form. It uses QuestionGrids which are automatically generated for each person involved in the form. There are a possible 3 responses to each of 4 questions. The options for each question are a -1, 0, or 1. I want a way to restrict how many -1's and 1's any member can give in response to a certain question for each person. My thought was that I have some way of checking the responses they give and keep track of the number of -1's and 1's in two variables. If a variable exceeds the amount which I set it throws them an error.

That's the best I could do for explaining my issue, but to help with clarity a bit more I'm including a code snippet and a picture of the question grid's format. If anything is still unclear please let me know.

Thank you for any help you could give!

Code Snippet:

```
function makeEvals(){
  var form = FormApp.create('Winter 2016 Evals');
  form.collectsEmail();
  form.setCollectEmail(true);
  var names = ['Person1','Person2','Person3','Person4'];
  for(var i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
    var questionGrid = form.addGridItem();
    questionGrid.setTitle(names[i]);
    questionGrid.setRows(['This person is actively engaged with floor','This person actively contributes time and energy to benefit House',
                          'This person reflects floor in a professional manner','This person is an overall good member of floor']);
    questionGrid.setColumns(['-1 (Does not meet expectations)','0 (Meets expectations)','1 (Exceeds expectations)']);
    questionGrid.setRequired(true);
```

[Image of question grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmORt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [tutorial](https://eyetea33.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/limit-responses-in-google-forms-using-google-apps-script/) wherein the function will check the number of responses and if it exceeds the limit you set, you can modify it to throw an [alert dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs). You can use `responses.length` to check the limit of responses that you want to set. Hope this helps!